# Create dict with incremental string date tuple values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to achieve the following result

```
   {"0": ('07:00', '07:30'),
    "1": ('07:30', '08:00'),
    "2": ('08:00', '08:30'),
    "3": ('08:30', '09:00'),
    "4": ('09:00', '09:30'),
    "5": ('09:30', '10:00')}
```

I am doing something like this:

```
routes = {str(int(slot)): (t1, t1+'30') for slot in list(np.arange(5)) for t1 in ???}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this result using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20time#datetime-objects) objects and adding a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20time#timedelta-objects) to them, converting into string representations using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20time#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = timedelta(minutes = 30)
t = datetime(1, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0)

routes = { str(slot) : ((t + d * slot).strftime('%H:%M'), (t + d * (slot + 1)).strftime('%H:%M')) for slot in range(6) }

print(routes)
```

Output:

```py
{
 '0': ('07:00', '07:30'),
 '1': ('07:30', '08:00'),
 '2': ('08:00', '08:30'),
 '3': ('08:30', '09:00'),
 '4': ('09:00', '09:30'),
 '5': ('09:30', '10:00')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
# Start at 7:00
init_hour = 7  # Initial hour
init_min = 0  # Initial minute
interval = 30  # Interval between slots (30 min)
num_slots = 10  # Number of slots

routes = {str(i): ("{}:{}".format(str(init_hour + (init_min + i*interval)//60).zfill(2), str((init_min + i*interval)%60).zfill(2)), "{}:{}".format(str(init_hour + (init_min + i*interval + interval)//60).zfill(2), str((init_min + i*interval + interval)%60).zfill(2))) for i in range(num_slots)}
```